# Android manifestmerger ignoring node=replace marker in Cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

In my Cordova app, I'm trying to change the behavior of an activity from a library (need to hide title bar); I added this to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

and got this error (paths on line 3 shortened for brevity):

```
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Merging manifests from project and 4 libraries.
[mergemanifest] Error: [.../app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:21, .../app/plugins/com.salesforce/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/AndroidManifest.xml:16] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity] element:
[mergemanifest]   <activity
[mergemanifest]       @android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
[mergemanifest] --    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
[mergemanifest]   <activity
[mergemanifest]       @android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
[mergemanifest] ++    @android:theme="@style/SalesforceSDK.ActionBarTheme">
```

I'd prefer not to modify the library's manifest, so I tried to override it in my app's manifest using markers [as described in the merger docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers).  First I added `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to my `<manifest>` element, then I updated the conflicting line:

```
<activity android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
          tools:replace="theme" />
```

It still fails, although you can see that it sees the new attribute:

```
[mergemanifest]   <activity
[mergemanifest]       @android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
[mergemanifest] --    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
[mergemanifest] --    @tools:replace="theme">
[mergemanifest] --</activity>
[mergemanifest]   <activity
[mergemanifest]       @android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.LoginActivity"
[mergemanifest] ++    @android:theme="@style/SalesforceSDK.ActionBarTheme">
[mergemanifest] ++</activity>
```

I also tried `tools:node=”replace”`, but from the examples in the docs, that should be on the parent (in this case, `application`), and I'd rather not do that without understanding all of the other merges that could be affected.  So, why is `tools:replace="theme"` being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify tag's attributes of Manifest just using `config-file` attribute in `plugin.xml` file.

In that particular case you have to add namespace to the root element of the plugin XML file.

```
<plugin id="myapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

and than

```
<config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge">
 <application tools:replace="android:label"/>
</config-file>
```

**Note**: never modify `AndroidManifest.xml` directly.